# Does it still make sense to create ChromeApps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

Chrome apps were [discontinued](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) **except for ChromeOS**. On desktop, [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) should be usable as almost drop-in replacement and on mobile [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) should. But what about the ChromeOS? Does it still make sense to package as ChromeApp for the benefit of users of that, or would the Cordova-based Android version be good enough?